# failed to use virtualenv in pycharm

Tags: django, pycharm

[image]

I actually have python file in scripts    but I can't import python in script while importing new environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starting a new virtual environment you need to have a directory which is empty.

Just select an **empty directory** it should work fine.

Comment: @Harry you can select answer if this helped. Thanks